# Unable program Atmega8a MCU using arduino

Tags: avr, bootloader

I am new in this. Bought Atmega8a mcu to have some fun with it. But I am unable to program it using arduino uno rev-3. Haven't used any external parts to program it. Just connected the chip as below:

- Arduino pin 10 to chip pin rst,
- Pin 11 to MOSI,
- Pin 12 to MISO,
- Pin 13 to SCK,
- Connected vcc and gnd to chip pin 7 & 8,
- Also used an 10 uf cap, arduino rst to gnd.

Trying to upload the bootloader using arduino ide 1.6.9. It says:

> avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
>       Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override this check

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Most minimal AVR setups include a 10k pull-up resistor on the reset pin. Are you sure you don't need one?

Comment: Please share an schematic.

Comment: [Datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-8159-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega8a_datasheet.pdf), page 58, figure 15-1. #RESET has an internal pullup resistor, external one isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

- Arduino target cpu (or variant) must be ATMega8A.
- "Invalid signature" is not so verbose - it says nothing. Enable verbose log for avrdude in Arduino setting.
- If signature is slightly different from actual one, it's selected variant problem.
- If it's something like 0xFF or 0x00 it's usualy wiring, reset or missing xtal problem.
- Bootloader needs correct xtal/resonator (AVR runs from internal 8MHz clock and it's divided by factor 8 by default, but after flashing bootloader it'll be set to crystal oscilator - depends on target/variant)
- Remove cap from RST, it might be slowing down reset and cause invalid reading

Answer (score 0):

1. Currently there's no arduino board with atmega8a as the main microcontroller.
2. You forgot about pins 20 and 22 -- **you must connect them to VCC and GND even if you're not going to use ADC.**

EDIT:
Ad. 1. It would be possible to add support for atmega8a to arduino ide, by modifying hardware/arduino/avr/boards.txt file and compiling a bootloader for atmega8a.